# How to do the ng-repeat when given a id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
var CoffeecatControllers = angular.module('CoffeecatControllers', []);

CoffeecatControllers.controller('CoffeeListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.coffees =
       [{'id': 2,
       'brand': "Jimmy's Coffee",
       'name': 'Mocha',
       'country': 'America',
       'reviews': [
       {'rating': 10,
       'comment': 'What everyone should drink in the morning!',
       'reviewer': 'Earl Lee Riser'
       },
       {'rating': 10,
       'comment': 'A genius of everything coffee',
       'reviewer': 'Bob'
       }
       ]
       },
       {'id': 3,
       'brand': "We Did Our Best",
       'name': 'Latte',
       'country': 'France',
       'reviews': [
       {'rating': 1,
       'comment': " a 'latte' yuckiness.",
       'reviewer': 'Tim Burr'
       },
       {'rating': 1,
       'comment': 'Is this even coffee?',
       'reviewer': 'Sue Flay'
       },
        {'rating': 1,
       'comment': 'The grossest thing I have ever had.',
       'reviewer': 'Myles Long'
       },
        {'rating': 5,
       'comment': 'I dont know what the fuss is about, i dont think its too bad!',
       'reviewer': 'Sara Bellum'
       }
       ]
       }
];
});`
```

With the data in the controller, how could I do the ng-repeator for the reviews where id=3? Such that the reviews in id=3 can be displayed as "rating","comment" and "reviewer"
Suppose we have already get the id in html "Reviews"

Much appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to extract from objects in arrays

```html
<div ng-app='CoffeecatControllers'>
<div ng-controller='CoffeeListCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='coffee in coffees | filter:coffee.id = 3'>
    {{coffee.brand}} 
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="CoffeecatControllers" ng-controller="CoffeeListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="list in coffees[1]">
        {{ list }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DieuNQ/kank3vrw/).

Hope this help.